# how to embed a github git README file on a website

Tags: javascript, git, curl, github, markdown

I am making a website for someone and they want to be able to have that site fetch the github readme markdown file at a certain URL and display it on the website, so that instead of having to write the readme in two places, it just pulls from github. Is that possible? How do I do it? I saw this:

https://github.com/coreyti/showdown

which turns markdown into html, but I'm still not how I would fetch the readme URL and convert it into an object that showdown could parse.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/). It allows you to publish your markdown document on Github and on others locations at the same time in Markdown or HTML format. For instance, you could publish the HTML on a public Google Drive or Dropbox location.

**NOTE:** I'm the developer of StackEdit

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this, great tool.

Comment: This doesn't allow the original git repo file to be embedded on a website unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Tool is advanced and lofty, but there is a lingereing issue that's still being on hold: [it inserts stackedit_data hash between edits in the end of file](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1237), which makes document impure.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub has an option to show file source, `Raw` button in top right corner. Raw link for your example is: https://raw.github.com/coreyti/showdown/master/README.md

Assuming that README file is formatted in Markdown already, you could just fetch source and format it on your side, libraries most probably already exist for your language.

**UPDATE**

I wouldn't actually download file from GitHub every time the page on your site is requested. GitHub may be down, connection may be slow -- and this will affect visitors of **your** site. Instead, you may want to have a cron job running on the server that would download a file from GitHub, say, every five minutes, and cache it locally. Then, every time you need to display the file, you'll read a local copy and don't depend on GitHub server being accessible. As a drawback, you will have a certain synchronization delay (5 minutes in my example).

Answer (score 1):

I’ve written *riss.awk* to [insert a README.md on your website](https://cj.rs/readme-in-static-site/?ref=so-16226202), optionally performing some transformations in the process.

> be able to have that site fetch the github readme

You can automatically fetch the original README.md file like this:

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cljoly/readme-in-static-site/main/README.md | awk -f riss.awk >readme-in-static-site.md
```

> convert it into an object that showdown could parse

I couldn’t find showdown’s documentation, but there might be some kind of API  you could use to upload the file generated above (`readme-in-static-site.md`)? A cronjob-like task could then run this process every few hours to keep things up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku seems to be doing it by copying the rendered html https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/stouffi/heroku-i18n-js-buildpack-ruby#buildpack-instructions